# Expected type of Parser in method "|"

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have the following code being compiled against scala 2.8.0:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.{syntactical,PackratParsers}
import syntactical.StandardTokenParsers

object MyParser extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers{
  lexical.reserved ++= Set("int","char","boolean")

  lazy val primitiveType:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[_]] = primitiveChar | primitiveInt | primitiveBool

  lazy val primitiveInt:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[Int]] = "int" ^^ { _ => PrimitiveType[Int]() }

  lazy val primitiveChar:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[Char]] = "char" ^^ { _ => PrimitiveType[Char]() }

  lazy val primitiveBool:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[Boolean]] = "boolean" ^^ { _ => PrimitiveType[Boolean]() }
}

object MyParser2 extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers{
  lexical.reserved ++= Set("int","char","boolean")

  lazy val primitiveType:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[_]] =  primitiveChar | primitiveIntOrBool

  lazy val primitiveIntOrBool:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[_]] = "int" ^^ { _ => PrimitiveType[Int]() } | "boolean" ^^ {_ => PrimitiveType[Boolean]()}

  lazy val primitiveChar:PackratParser[PrimitiveType[Char]] = "char" ^^ { _ => PrimitiveType[Char]()} 
}

case class PrimitiveType[T]()
```

Compiling MyParser1 gives:

```
error: inferred type arguments  [this.PrimitiveType[_ >: _1 with Boolean <: AnyVal]] do not conform to method |'s type parameter bounds [U >: this.PrimitiveType[_ >: Char with Int <: AnyVal]]
```

I believe it fails because of the | method type signature, defined as:

```
def | [U >: T](q: => Parser[U]): Parser[U]
```

why does U have to be a supertype of T? What should be the return value of "primitiveType"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your last line into

```
case class PrimitiveType[+T]()
```

This allows for PrimitiveType[Int] <: PrimitiveType[AnyVal] which is needed when you want to merge the results of PrimitiveType[Boolean] and PrimitiveType[Int] parsers via |.

BTW, I would also suggest to write

```
PrimitiveType[AnyVal]
```

instead of

```
PrimitiveType[_]
```

since this is more precise in your case.

Comment: Thanks, of course that solved my problem. However, I'm still missing why is U >: T required in |.

Comment: @kmels `U` must be a supertype of `T` because `|` constructs a compound parser which will produce either `T` or `U`. In practice, given `T | S`, the compiler will search for a *least upper bound* of `T` and `S` in the type hierarchy, and call that `U`.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better changing your generic `case class PrimitiveType[T]` to a class hierarchy.  The generic type parameters aren't available at runtime, so you won't be able to do much with your parse results...

This would give you the following (<strike>untested code</strike> now tested):

```
object MyParser extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers{
  lexical.reserved ++= Set("int","char","boolean")

  lazy val primitiveType:Parser[PrimitiveType] = primitiveChar | primitiveInt | primitiveBool

  lazy val primitiveInt:PackratParser[PrimitiveType] = "int" ^^^ PrimitiveInt

  lazy val primitiveChar:PackratParser[PrimitiveType] = "char" ^^^ PrimitiveChar

  lazy val primitiveBool:PackratParser[PrimitiveType] = "boolean" ^^^ PrimitiveBoolean
}

sealed trait PrimitiveType
case object PrimitiveInt extends PrimitiveType
case object PrimitiveChar extends PrimitiveType
case object PrimitiveBoolean extends PrimitiveType
```